# adding a #hash to each link in list_pages()?

Tags: list, functions

hey guys,
is it somehow possible to do the following:

`wp_list_pages()` lists each link inside a `<li> <a href="link"...`

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&exclude='); ?>
```

Is it possible to add a #hash to those links? Like `<a href="link#something"`?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap it in a function (save it in `functions.php`);

```
function wp_list_pages_with_hash( $hash, $args = '' )
{
    $add_hash = create_function( '$link', 'return $link . "#' . $hash . '";' );
    add_filter( 'page_link', $add_hash );
    $result = wp_list_pages( $args );
    remove_filter( 'page_link', $add_hash );
    return $result; // back compat in case 'echo' was null  
}
```

Then call it like so!

```
<?php wp_list_pages_with_hash( 'target', 'title_li=&depth=0' ); ?>
```